# SQL server 2008 - storing and searching URL (web address)

Tags: sql-server-2008, url, search, sql-like

I'm facing a decision on how to store URL (bookmark) in a table. I have following requirements:

> Customer must be able to search the title of a bookmark.

I decided to use a FTS with ranking option for this requirement

> Customer must be able to search an address

Here is where I have doubts on how to store URL. First of all, URLs must be unique in my table. This will potentially be a very large table. There will be no updates or deletes on this table. What I had in mind is this

```
ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) -- identity and foreign key in other table(s)
Title [nvarchar](500) -- title (FTS)
CompleteURL [nvarchar](300), -- Unique index example: http://www.bbc.co.uk
URLPrefix [nvarchar](20), -- example: http://www
URLSufix [nvarchar](280), -- example: bbc.co.uk/something (index)
```

I realize I have data duplication but I have no problem with that since data integrity is not at stake here (no updates or deletes) and performance is important. I was thinking to use **CompleteURL** as my **IF EXISTS** column during insert. I'm not sure if this approach will provide better performance than composite key on **URLPrefix and URLSufix** and to completely lose **CompleteURL**?

**URLSufix** would provide quick find for search parameter **LIKE 'bbc%'**.

But what if customer does search **LIKE 'www.bbc%'** ? Any wildcards on beginning of a string (%bbc%) are out of the question since I cannot afford scan of entire table.

Furthermore, i decided to move URLs longer than (300) in another table since there more than 99.9% of URLs are not that long and I don't want to hit the index limit of 900 bytes.
Is this a good practice?

**EDIT:**

To make a long story short. How would you store this bookmark

```
BBC Homepage title
http://www.bbc.co.uk/
```

if you want it to be returned when search parameter is one of 3 cases:

```
1. 'homepage'
2. 'bbc.co'
3. 'www.bbc.co'
```

Comment: Looks like the user stories is not clear to you. Before you start thinking about the design, ask your customer sole use cases.

Comment: FYI: Suffix is spelled with two _effs_.

Comment: Why not use FTS on the urls as well? Word breaker would ignore punctuation anyways.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are using SQL Server 2005 (or SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2), you can configure the full text search functionality on the URL columns, so you can avoid using the LIKE operator as a whole (event %bbc% will take much less time now).

Now, if you have configured full-text search on title,and complete URL, you can use contains clause of SQL to search what you are looking for.